# Transform a pandas column of lists of dicts into new columns

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
     ID    Assigned
0    123   [{'COD': 990, 'NAME': 'Alice'}]
1    456   [{'COD': 990, 'NAME': 'Alice'}, {'COD': 991, 'NAME': 'Bob'}]
```

I need to transform it to this:

```
ID    COD      NAME
123   990      Alice
456   990      Alice
456   991      Bob
```

If the list only had one element I know (from other SO answers) that I could do something like

```
pd.DataFrame(df['Assigned'].apply(lambda x: x[0]).tolist())
```

but I'm stuck on how to deal with cases where the list in the `Assigned` column contains multiple dictionaries (as in the second row).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution :

```
df=df.set_index('ID').Assigned.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index().drop('level_1',axis=1)
pd.concat([df,df[0].apply(pd.Series)],axis=1)

Out[78]: 
    ID                              0  COD   NAME
0  123  {'COD': 990, 'NAME': 'Alice'}  990  Alice
1  456  {'COD': 990, 'NAME': 'Alice'}  990  Alice
2  456    {'COD': 991, 'NAME': 'Bob'}  991    Bob
```

---

Data Input:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[123,456],'Assigned':[[{'COD': 990, 'NAME': 'Alice'}],[{'COD': 990, 'NAME': 'Alice'}, {'COD': 991, 'NAME': 'Bob'}]]})
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option based on numpy and apply pd.DataFrame i.e

```
ids = df['ID'][np.arange(len(df)).repeat(df.Assigned.str.len(), 0)]
ndf = pd.concat(df['Assigned'].apply(pd.DataFrame).values,0).set_index(ids).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    ID  COD   NAME
0  123  990  Alice
1  456  990  Alice
2  456  991    Bob
```